# XML jQuery get multiple nodes with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a part of an XML file that looks like this:

```
<paymentTypes>
<paymentType>type1</paymentType>
<paymentType>type2</paymentType>
<paymentType>type3</paymentType>
<paymentType>type4</paymentType>
</paymentTypes>
```

The thing is that I want to get it via ajax jQuery, but if I try this:

```
var paymentTypes = $(xml).find("paymentTypes").text()
```

the output will be type1type2type3type4.

What function should I use(built-in or should I write it) in order to get the results on separate lines?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
In my XML file there are multiple items, each of them with their own  entry.

Comment: what is the desired output? do you need an array of the text values

Comment: if so `var paymentTypes = $(xml).find("paymentType").map(function(){return $(this).text()}).get()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny it should be `paymentType`, not `paymentTypes`.

Comment: The desired output is type1\n type2\n type3\n type4

Comment: @Matei_Radu should this output be in console or in page (with `<br/>` instead of `\n`)?

Comment: The purpose of this ajax get is to finally add it in page, either as an unordered list, either as a text, but each on different lines. The thing is that the code above should work of there were only one entry, but in my XML there are hundreds of stores, each of them with their own payment types.

Comment: Not sure that I understood correctly... Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axggjdfr/) desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

u can iterate over the result append to new string

```
var xml ='<paymentTypes><paymentType>type1</paymentType><paymentType>type2</paymentType><paymentType>type3</paymentType><paymentType>type4</paymentType></paymentTypes>';

var result = "";
$(xml).find('paymentType').each(function(i,v){
    result += $(v).text()+'\n';
});
console.log(result);
```