# Loading XML via JQuery - operate multiple results

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm using AJAX to load an XML file in to a HTML div. My XML looks like this:

```
<Incidents>
  <Incident id="123">
    <ModTime>2016-01-23T08:00:00Z</ModTime>
    <comments>comments here</comments>
    <currentUpdate>update</currentUpdate>
    <status>Active</status>
  </incident>
  <Incidents>
    <Incident id="456">
      <ModTime>2016-01-23T08:00:00Z</ModTime>
      <comments>comments here</comments>
      <currentUpdate>update</currentUpdate>
      <status>Active</status>
    </incident>
```

```js
//<![CDATA[
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "feed.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    $('#table').append('<h2>XML</h2>'); 
    $('#table').append('<table id="show_table" border="1" >'); 
    $(xml).find('Incident').each(function() {
      var $feed = $(this);
      var id = $feed.attr("id");
      var mod = $feed.find('ModTime').text();
      var comments = $feed.find('comments').text();
      var update = $feed.find('currentUpdate').text();
      var status = $feed.find('status').text();
      var html = ' <tr><td >' + id + '</td><td >' + mod + '<br>' + comments     + '</td><td>' + update + '</td><td>'  + status +'</td><td > </tr>';
      $('#show_table').append(html);
    });
  }  
});
```

Which works fine most of the time, however sometimes incidents in the XML will have two comment sections.

```
<Incidents>
  <Incident id="123">
    <ModTime>2016-01-23T08:00:00Z</ModTime>
    <comments>comments here</comments>
    <currentUpdate>update</currentUpdate>
    <status>Active</status>
  </incident>
  <Incidents>
    <Incident id="456">
      <ModTime>2016-01-23T08:00:00Z</ModTime>
      <comments>comments here</comments>
      <comments>comments another comment</comments>
      <currentUpdate>update</currentUpdate>
      <status>Active</status>
    </incident>
```

When that happens I want to separate them out but I can't work out how?

I first tried adding a line break in the table but realized that was too late as I'd already got the data.

I then tried adding the break when I find the comments but that also didn't work - it just added a break at the end of the

```
var comments = $feed.find('comments').text() + '<br>';
```

Comment: That XML seems to have some syntax issues

Comment: That's my simplifying the XML - the XML I'm getting works fine. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118696/xml-jquery-get-multiple-nodes-with-same-name seems to be very similar to my problem. I just need to work out how to adapt it to my table rather than a list.